# Why $\frac{\chi^2}{number\,of\,data\,points - 1} \approx 1$ means good fit?

Tags: chi-squared-test, degrees-of-freedom

In my statistics class, I learned that if $\frac{\chi^2}{number\,of\,data\,points - 1} \approx 1$ the fitting of the model to the data points is good. I do not really understand why this statement is true. Can anyone explain for me? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would help to add the context in which you saw this.  I've seen it used in the case of Deviance Goodness of Fit Tests for GLM.  My answer is inspired by that.

A chisquare's mean is equal to it's degrees of freedom (depending on the scenario, this could be number of data points less one, but if the model has parameters then it would be data points - parameters for covariates - 1). Thus, if a chisquare statistic divided by its degrees of freedom is near one, then this means the chi-square statistic is not too far from its mean and thus not very extreme.

For tests deviance goodness of fit test (in which rejection of the null means a lack of fit), model is a good fit because if the model were not a good fit, we would see a larger chi-square statistic than expected.